# Dynamically add Menu in MenuBar of ApplicationWindow in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to create an application that is extensible with plugins. Now the plugins should be able to add a Menu dynamically in the MenuBar.

From documentation I can find a MenuBar that is provided by QtLabsPlatform. This has a method addMenu. But Windows was not in the list of supported platforms. So I cannot benefit from it.

I tried the placeholder technique suggested in [Error adding a Menu in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142565/error-adding-a-menu-in-qml), but this does not work with QtQuick.Controls 2.13

Answer (score 4):

In [the @timday answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32149832/6622587) in the question you indicate indicates the answer but does not show an example:

> ...
>   **Dynamic creation of Menus is a little harder; see Qt.createQmlObject
>   or Qt.createComponent docs**. (It may be simpler to just declare all the
>   ones you need in your code, but with their visible property wired to
>   whatever logic is appropriate). ...

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So my answer is just to show you how to do it although I think you want to add MenuItem to a Menu dynamically, instead of a Menu to a MenuBar:

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13


ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            id: plugins_menu
            title: qsTr("&Plugins")   
        }
    }
    function onTriggered(item){
        console.log(item.text)
    }
    Component.onCompleted:{
        var plugin_names = ["plugin1", "plugin2", "plugin3"]
        for(var i in plugin_names){
            var item = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.13; import QtQuick.Controls 2.13; MenuItem {}',
                                       plugins_menu)
            item.text = plugin_names[i]
            plugins_menu.addItem(item)
            var f = function(it){ 
                it.triggered.connect(function (){ root.onTriggered(it)
            })}
            f(item)
        }
    }
}
```